# SwiftUI - Unable to set background color of List in iOS 15 (works in iOS 14)

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui

My iPad app makes use of a 3-column layout using SwiftUI's `NavigationView`, 2 `List`s, and then the content view.  The first `List` acts as the primary navigation screen, and the (relevant) code looks roughly like this:

```
var body: some View {
    List {
          ...snip...
        }
    }
    .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
    .accentColor(.white)
    .introspectTableView { tableView in
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(Color.blue)
    }
    .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: { self.isCreating = true }) {
        Label("", systemImage: "plus")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    })
}
```

As shown in the code, I was using the awesome [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) library to get access to the underlying `UITableView` so I could set the background color.  In iOS 14 this renders properly, as a List with a blue background.  (See screenshot below)

[image]

However, in iOS 15 the background color is not applied.  (See screenshot)

[image]

I have tried a couple different methods for setting the background color in iOS 15.  The Introspect code doesn't seem to get called at all, so I tried:

```
List {
}
.background(Color.blue)
```

That did absolutely nothing.  I also tried setting `UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor` to the appropriate value, however that will change the background of all `UITableView`s globally.  That is not the behavior I want.  I only want this one `List` to have that background color.

Is this a bug in iOS 15 or SwiftUI?  Is there a new way for setting the background color on a List?  Does this have something to do with the fact that my `listStyle` is set to `SidebarListStyle`?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Introspect is a hack for SwiftUI, every place where you use it is under risk of stop working with any next iOS update, even minor. I would not recommend to use it for production - only for investigations.

Answer (score 5):

I managed to change the background of list with:

```swift
List {

   Section("Section") {
      /// ...
   }
   .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
}
.listStyle(.plain)
.background(.blue)
```

Comment: Annoying that this only works with list style plain and not with the default style with rounded corners, ie grouped.

Comment: The best solution over my research ))

Answer (score 1):

you could try a combination of things, such as in this example:

EDIT1: to make it work with the sidebar, tested on iPad ios15.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let data = (1...10).map{ String($0) }
    
    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear // <-- here
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea() // <-- here blue background
                List {
                    ForEach(data, id: \.self) { tx in
                        // Text(tx).foregroundColor(.white) // <-- white text
                      NavigationLink(tx, destination: Text("destination " + tx)).foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                    .listRowBackground(Color.blue) // <-- list row matching background
                }
                .listStyle(.sidebar) // <-- here
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

EDIT2: avoiding global color change.

Ok, whenever you action another view,
put the color back, such as in this example using `onTapGesture`.
You can also use `onDisappear` or `onAppear`
or any other scheme to change the color for all future views, depending on your needs.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let data = (1...10).map{ String($0) }
    @State var activate: Bool = false
    @State var selection: String?
    
    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear // <-- here
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea() // <-- here blue background
                List {
                    ForEach(data, id: \.self) { tx in
                        NavigationLink(tx, destination: SecView(text: tx), tag: tx, selection: $selection)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .onTapGesture() {
                                // --- here --- whatever color you want
                                UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .systemGroupedBackground
                                selection = tx
                            }
                    }.listRowBackground(Color.blue) // <-- list row matching background
                } .listStyle(.sidebar) // <-- here
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecView: View {
    @State var text: String
    let data = (1...10).map{ String($0) }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(data, id: \.self) { tx in
                NavigationLink(text + " " + tx, destination: SecView(text: tx))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would I still get a layout similar to SidebarListStyle?  (Grouping, collapsable sections, etc.)  Is there a way to mimic that manually?

Comment: updated my answer to cater for the sidebar.

Comment: So, again, I know I could use UITableView.appearance(), however that changes EVERY List.  I only want to change this one.  I don't want to make a global change.

Comment: updated my answer with a possible solution to avoid global background color setting. Works well for me.