# Change color view on SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, background-color

I can't find a solution to change my background color view, I tried a lot of options and nothing works.

I'm trying solutions but the isn't changing

There is my struct of the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {        
            VStack {
                Text("Trying ColorView")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                Button("ColorView") {
                    
                }
            }      
        .accentColor(Color.black)
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You've got about six views there, but none with any actual content. Which one do you want to change, and how will you know it's changed if it doesn't contain anything visible?

Comment: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69667730/swiftui-unable-to-set-background-color-of-list-in-ios-15-works-in-ios-14  it may be useful to address your vague question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have already mistakes in your posted code above, your XCode should normally tell you that.

Which view you want to change..?
This might be a solution... You can change it like you need it.

```
struct testViewTwo: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                VStack(spacing: -15) {
                HStack {
                    HStack {
                       Text("Hello World")
                    }.background(Color.blue)
                }.foregroundColor(Color.white)
            }
        }.background(Image("Background"))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You change a background color with the background modifier.

If you want to change the background color of the whole view, you should create a ZStack that spans the whole view with a background modifier.

```swift
ZStack { 
    ...
}
.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
.background(Color(.blue)
```

Comment: Yeah that's a solution what I tried and nothing changes...

Comment: Would you mind updating your question ? What exactly do you want to achieve and what have you already tried ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **Color("Green")** to change the color. Here's a sample.

```
var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView{
        VStack {
            VStack(spacing: 15){
                 HStack {
                     Color("Green")
                       .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```